# sorting array of arrays using one of their indexes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array with different values in it and I'd like to sort it by the numeric value in one of the indexes

```
const arr = [
  ['foo', var, 5],
  ['fee', var, 7],
  ['faa', var, 3]
]
```

I want to sort this array from big to small using `arr[2]` value. Any idea how it can be done?

the desire outcome should be:

```
const arr = [
  ['fee', var, 7],
  ['foo', var, 5],
  ['faa', var, 3]      
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  return a[2] < b[2] // To sort in descending order
  // return a[2] > b[2] // To sort in ascending order
})
```

Example:

```js
var arr = [
  ['foo', 'fifth', 5],
  ['fee', 'seventh', 7],
  ['faa', 'third', 3]
];

var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[2] < b[2]
});

console.log(sortedArr)
```

## Here's how sort function work

First, let's assume this array:

```
[1,2] // where a = 1, b = 2
```

**Ascending order:**

Is a greater than b?

> If it is yes, we need to sort => return true
>
> Else, we don't need to sort => return false

**Descending order:**

Is a lesser than b?

> If it is yes, we need to sort => return true
>
> Else, we don't need to sort => return false

In preceding example, we're verifying if a is lesser than b, then return true to sort it out else return false as this is already in descending order.

---

As per @[Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)

> Please do not return a Boolean value for sorting, because sort needs a value smaller than zero, zero or greater than zero. To omit equal cases may actually work, but it make for the **algorithm harder to get the array to sort**.

You should consider returning 0, 1, or -1. For your case, you should use like this:

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a[2] < b[2]) return 1
  if(a[2] > b[2]) return -1
  if(a[2] === b[2]) return 0
})
```

---

**Furthermore**

If the values are only integers (doesn't contain Infinity and NaN), then it can be simplifies as below,

```
arr.sort((a,b) => b[2]-a[2])
```

Comment: please do not return a boolean value for sorting, because sort needs a value smaller than zero, zeor or greater than zero. to omit equal cases may actually work, but it make for the algorithm harder to get the array to sort.

Comment: should be `arr.sort((a,b) => b[2] - a[2])`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
function bubbleSort(arr){
   var len = arr.length;
   for (var i = len-1; i>=0; i--){
     for(var j = 1; j<=i; j++){
       if(arr[j-1]<arr[j]){
           var temp = arr[j-1];
           arr[j-1] = arr[j];
           arr[j] = temp;
        }
     }
   }
   return arr;
}

console.log( bubbleSort([7,5,2,4,3,9]))
```

console.log out put is 9 7 5 4 3 2
Modify the code to loop through your object.var in Array