# How to sort elements in an array into order and even numbers and they should be in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i am currently learning how to program using javascript, i came across a problem ( Write function that sort an array with odd first and even later
// sortArray([3,24,1,4,9,10]) => [1,3,9,4,10,24]
// sortArray([2,1,4,9,3,3,10,12]) => [1,3,3,9,2,4,10,12]), i have implemented a solution making use of the sort function and multiple variables. See code below;

```js
  function sortingArr (array) {
    let sortedArr = (array.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })), oddArr = [], evenArr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (sortedArr[i] % 2 == 0){
            evenArr.push(sortedArr[i]);
        }
        else {
            oddArr.push(sortedArr[i]);
        }
    }
    return oddArr.concat(evenArr);
}
console.log (sortingArr ([2,1,4,9,3,3,10,12]));
```

I would appreciate suggestions I can use to solve the same problem with minimal memory allocation and runtime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890658/sorting-array-of-arrays-using-one-of-their-indexes/50890710#50890710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting on 'a' having a smaller modulus 2 than 'b'
OR 'a' is bigger than 'b'.

```js
function sortArrayUnevenFirst (array) {
    return array.sort(function(a,b){return b%2-a%2 || a-b});
}
console.log (sortArrayUnevenFirst([12,10,2,1,4,9,3,3]));
console.log (sortArrayUnevenFirst(['12','10','2','1','4','9','3','3']));
```

A modulus 2 can only be 0 for the even, and 1 for the uneven.

So when a%2==0 (even) and b%2==1 (uneven) then 'a' is put after 'b'.
And when a%2 equals b%2, then the size decides which comes first.

Comment: now it look like a copy of mine.

Comment: Indeed, but even before your post I came to the conclusion that `a%2<b%2` wasn't completely correct. So after some extra testing I had to fix that regardless of other answers.  And changing `a>b` to `a-b` is just done so that also strings with numbers are sorted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a group for sorting even and odd numbers and then sort by value with a chained approach.

```js
function sort(array) {
    return array.sort((a, b) => b % 2 - a % 2 || a - b)
}

console.log(sort([3, 24, 1, 4, 9, 10]));
console.log(sort([2, 1, 4, 9, 3, 3, 10, 12]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your own compare function to `sort`.

```js
const sorted = [2,1,4,9,3,3,10,12].sort((a, b) => {
    if(a % 2 === 1 && b % 2 === 1) return a - b;
    if(a % 2 === 1) return -1;
    if(b % 2 === 1) return 1;
    return a - b
})
console.log(sorted);
```