# Explanation of .sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have what may seem to be a basic question about the [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method in Javascript.

I just need a little more "down-to-earth" explanation about how this works:

If I have an array:

`var myArray = [40, 50, 30, 70];`

I want to sort `myArray` from smallest to largest, I would do:

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a-b;
});
```

So, stepping through that...

- 40 - 50 = -10 ... so since the value `-10` is less than `0`.. keep as is.
- 50 - 30 = 20 ... so since the value `20` is greater than `0`.. rearrange array to:

`[40,30,50,70]`.

So, once the rearrangement is done.. I assume does the `sort` method start over?

Sorry, if this is super basic, but just curious.. maybe I'm missing something that happens.

Comment: This may also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890658/sorting-array-of-arrays-using-one-of-their-indexes/50890710#50890710

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm